# which version of gsoap is the most stable under ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gsoap, apache-spark-standalone, http-status-code-505

I have been using the GSoap API and have different responses based on OS + GSoap combination. For GSoap gsoap_2.8.26, I run a developed Stand Alone GSoap Server and get the following when I do :http://22.22.222.222:8075/?conmony.wsdl, I get:

> ```
> >     <definitions xmlns:tns="urn:monyServer" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
> > xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
> > xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> > xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:am="urn:conmony"
> > xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
> > xmlns:HTTP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
> > xmlns:MIME="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
> > xmlns:DIME="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/dime/wsdl/"
> > xmlns:WSDL="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
> > xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="conmony"
> > targetNamespace="urn:monyServer"> <types> <schema
> > xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
> > xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
> > xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> > xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:am="urn:conmony"
> > xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:conmony"
> > elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
> > <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
> > <complexType name="struct-DBJOBSRET"> <!--  am__struct_DBJOBSRET  -->
> > <sequence> <element name="TENANTID" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1"
> > maxOccurs="1"/> <!--  am__struct_DBJOBSRET::TENANTID  --> <element
> > name="CustomerID" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::CustomerID  --> <element name="ServiceAddrID"
> > type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::ServiceAddrID  --> <element name="JobID"
> > type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::JobID  --> <element name="GeneratedJobNo"
> > type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::GeneratedJobNo  --> <element name="Purpose"
> > type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::Purpose  --> <element name="JobReferenceID"
> > type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::JobReferenceID  --> <element
> > name="SpecialInstructions" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"
> > maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::SpecialInstructions  --> <element
> > name="IsArchived" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::IsArchived  --> <element name="RecLockType"
> > type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::RecLockType  --> <element name="RecLockID"
> > type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::RecLockID  --> <element name="RecLockHost"
> > type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::RecLockHost  --> <element name="RecLockPID"
> > type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::RecLockPID  --> <element name="RecLockTS"
> > type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::RecLockTS  --> <element name="ReturnCode"
> > type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::ReturnCode  --> <element name="KeyID"
> > type="xsd:double" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::KeyID  --> <element name="Message"
> > type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/> <!-- 
> > am__struct_DBJOBSRET::Message  --> </sequence> </complexType>
> > <complexType name="JOBSRETItems"> <!--  am__JOBSRETItems  -->
> > <sequence> <element name="item" type="am:struct-DBJOBSRET"
> > minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="false"/> </sequence>
> > </complexType> <!--  operation request element  --> <element
> > name="scheduleCreateFirst"> <complexType> <sequence> <element
> > name="in-TENANTID" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- 
> > am__scheduleCreateFirst::in_TENANTID  --> <element
> > name="in-CustomerID" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!--
> > am__scheduleCreateFirst::in_CustomerID  --> <element
> > name="in-ServiceAddrID" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
> > <!--  am__scheduleCreateFirst::in_ServiceAddrID  --> <element
> > name="in-Purpose" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
> > nillable="true"/> <!--  am__scheduleCreateFirst::in_Purpose  -->
> > <element name="in-SpecialInstructions" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"
> > maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/> <!-- 
> > am__scheduleCreateFirst::in_SpecialInstructions  --> <element
> > name="in-CrewToDoWorkID" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
> > <!--  am__scheduleCreateFirst::in_CrewToDoWorkID  --> <element
> > name="in-DateTaskScheduled" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"
> > maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/> <!-- 
> > am__scheduleCreateFirst::in_DateTaskScheduled  --> <element
> > name="in-CancelUpToDate" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
> > nillable="true"/> <!--  am__scheduleCreateFirst::in_CancelUpToDate 
> >     --> <element name="in-InvoicePref" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/> <!--
> ```
>
> am__scheduleCreateFirst::in_InvoicePref  -->
>
> > Service definition of function am__scheduleCreateFirst
> >      
> >      
> >      
> >        
> >           
> >      gSOAP 2.8.26 generated service
> >     definition

**But when I use the same code on Ubuntu 16.04 with GSoap 2.8.45 on Ubuntu 16.04, I get the following:**   which seems to be some kind of 505 error. This is the case for the *exact same code*

> in message exchange Error 505:
>   HTTP 505 HTTP Version not supported

Here are the request and response Headers

---

### NOT WORKING

```
> Request headers:
> 
>    Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*   
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate    Accept-Language: en-US   
> Connection: Keep-Alive    Host: 45.76.234.222:8075    User-Agent:
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
> 
> Response Headers:
> 
>    Connection: close    Content-Length: 417    Content-Type: text/xml;
> charset=utf-8    Server: gSOAP/2.8
```

---

### WORKING

```
> Request Headers:
> 
>    Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*   
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate    Accept-Language: en-US   
> Connection: Keep-Alive    Host: 99.48.224.222:8075    User-Agent:
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
> 
> Response:
> 
>    Connection: keep-alive    Content-Length: 6849    Content-Type:
> text/xml    Server: gSOAP/2.8
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

False alarm. Disregard the post. I found that it was due to looking for a specific setting of an environment variable in the coding. Mods, if you can remove this post that would be great :-)